# Greatest lower bound property and least upper bound property: exercise

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I know I must be overlooking something here, but I currently am stuck with the following issue.

Consider the set $\boldsymbol{S = (a, b) \cup [c, d)}$, with $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}, c > b$.

I know that in order to claim that $S$ does satisfy the greatest lower bound property we must verify that for **every** non-empty subset $B \subseteq S$ bounded below in $S$ the maximum of the set of all lower bounds of $B$ is in $S$.

On the other hand, since there is a theorem that establishes that both greatest lower bound  property (*glb*) and least upper bound property (*lub*) necessarily imply each other, observing that $S$ fails to satisfy *lub* —**and it does**— should suffice to claim that it also fails to satify *glb*.

Allow me to show that *lub* fails to be satisfied.

Consider $E = (a, b)$. $E$ is a non-empty subset of $S$. Does it have any upper bound in $S$? Yes: $[c, d)$ is the set of upper bounds of $E$ that also happen to lie in $S$. The minimum of these upper bounds is $c$.

Now, the set of **all** upper bounds of $E$ —not restricting ourselves to just the ones that are in $S$— is $[b, +\infty)$. The minimum is $b$. **There you have it: $\boldsymbol{c \neq b}$, and thus *lub* does not hold.**

Then, *glb* does not hold either, and it should be possible to find a non-empty subset of $S$ bounded below in $S$ such that the maximum of the set of all lower bounds of that subset is **not** in $S$. **The problem is that I just can not find such a subset of $\boldsymbol{S}$**.

I tested on $[c, d)$. The set of its lower bounds in $S$ is $(a, b) \cup \{c\}$. Maximum: $c$. The set of **all** of its lower bounds is $(-\infty, c]$. Maximum: $c$. **No discrepancy.**

Am I not getting the concepts right?

Comment: Upon having posted my question I reckon I might have misunderstood what it means to possess glb. Now I believe it doesn't mean that the maximum of the set of all lower bounds of $B$ is in $S$, but rather it guarantees that the set of lower bounds of $B$ that are in $S$ does have a maximum —i.e. it is an interval that includes its own upper limit— regardless of whether it coincides with the maximum of the set of **all** lower bounds of $B$. 

**Could someone confirm this?**

Comment: I'm not sure because it depends on how you define the greatest lower bound property.  But if the glb can be in $\Bbb R$ (which I suspect is the case based on the theorem you cite above), then your reasoning fails.  It really depends on how your book defines the property.